# Mycert.pem does not exist while instally ipython notebook on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipython, jupyter

I am currently trying to install jupyter notebook on aws.
but there is an error showing that "mycert.pem" does not exit.

I ran the following line on my local terminal and get mykey.key & mycert.pem in local documents

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mykey.key -out mycert.pem
```

code in my jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c= get_config()
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always in your notebook

c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/Users/leigh/mycert.pem ' #location of your certificate file
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/Users/leigh/mykey.key '
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:eaa28116dc5f:________'
```

when I ran "jupyter notebook" on aws
it shows the following error

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-114>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1007, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 868, in init_webapp
xheaders=self.trust_xheaders)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/util.py", line 215, in __new__
instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 155, in initialize
read_chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 112, in __init__
self.ssl_options['certfile'])
ValueError: certfile "/Users/leigh/mycert.pem " does not exist
```

"/Users/leigh/mycert.pem"  is the path where mycert.pem on my local laptop.

Am i getting anything wrong D:?
Have tried to solved this for several hours but have no idea what is going on...
Would appreiciate a lot of anyone can kindly let me know how I can solve this problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate key & cert into the jupyter configuration folder:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ~/.jupyter/key.key -out ~/.jupyter/cert.pem
```

edit `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` and add:

```
import os
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.jupyter/key.key'
c.NotebookApp.certfile = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.jupyter/cert.pem'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using the correct certfile - the file itself should be on your instance, not on your "local laptop".

Move it to your instance, find its location, and then update your jupyter_notebook_config.py file.

Answer (score 0):

use cert.pem instead of key.key

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ~/.jupyter/cert.pem -out ~/.jupyter/cert.pem
```

also make sure to check the permission of the cert.pem . You probably have to use this command for that `sudo chmod 777 cert.pem`